# How to call method in secondary @interface in .h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface, objective-c-category, method-call

I have two @interface in single .h file. I want to access a method in secondary @interface.

My header file's name is MyImage.h

```
@interface MyImage : NSObject

- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image forName:(NSString*)fileName;

- (void)clearImageCache;

@end

@interface UIImageView (URL_Loading)

- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url;

- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
   placeholderAsSpinner:(BOOL)spinnerEnabled;

@end
```

Can anybody tell me how to call setImageWithURL: method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`@interface UIImageView (URL_Loading)`**

is a category of `UIImageView` so it is adding 2 new methods.

Import `header` and call it within a `UIImageView`

Example:

**`[yourImageView setImageWithURL:url];`**

Answer (score 1):

Just import the **category** in whichever file you want to use it.

```
#import "UIImageView+URL_Loading.h"
```

and then you can access its methods.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[imgView setImageWithURL:url];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All I needed was to import it without .h extension

Comment: Methods can be called. But it shows an error UIImageView+URL_Loading 'file not found'